# SQL Query to retrieve Count

Tags: sql, linq

With my SQL getting rusty I'm trying hard to get this working. 
I have a table with multiple entries as shown in the attached image.
I need to write a query so that it returns me the count of the number of entries. i.e, 7 in this case. which is a distinct combination of MainID, ItemID, DeviceID, and ChannelID

Thanks for your help!!

[image: database image]

Comment: `GROUP BY MainID, ItemID, DeviceID, ChannelID` and count. This will give you the count of all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Select 
  Count(*)
From
(
Select
  Distinct
  MainID,
  ItemID,
  DeviceID,
  ChannelID
From
  yourtable
)X;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #T
    END

CREATE TABLE #T (
    MainId INT
    ,ItemId INT
    ,DeviceId INT
    ,ChannelId INT
)

INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1,1,2,1),(1,1,2,2),(1,1,2,3),(1,1,22,0),(1,2,1,1),(1,2,1,2)
,(1,2,1,3),(1,2,2,1),(1,2,2,2),(1,2,2,3),(1,2,3,1),(1,2,3,2),(1,2,3,3),(1,2,4,1)
,(1,2,4,2),(1,2,4,3),(1,2,5,1),(1,2,5,2),(1,2,5,3)

SELECT MainId, ItemId, DeviceId, COUNT(*) as RecordCount
FROM
    #T
GROUP BY
    MainId, ItemId, DeviceId

SELECT DISTINCT MainId, ItemId, DeviceId
FROM
    #T

SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MainId, ItemId, DeviceId) as GroupNumber
FROM
    #t
```

As I have previously stated the reason you are having difficulty is that you are including ChannelId into your query and that of the other answers.  If ChannelId is included it means that there will be more than 7 Distinct combinations of records.  And no my original query did not return more than 7 records it returned only 7 records and the count of how many records of that combination of columns.

I have updated with 3 examples including sample data, which I urge you to do for people next time as you are asking us for help so make it easy provide DML statements rather than an image of your test case!

Example 1 simply adds the group by columns into my original query so you could see what I was talking about and was a little oversight.

Example 2 is the distinct which is basically the same as #1.

Example 3 if you want all of the other data like you have specified in other comments you would actually want to use a windowed function if your DBMS supports it, but of course this doesn't translate perfectly to linq.  But you would need to use DENSE_RANK() to get the grouping the way you want it.

Comment: This Query doesn't work as expected. It returns more than 7 records

Comment: @this-Me I updated my answer to give you some more insight but your comment was blatantly wrong, it only returned you 7 records.  Hopefully this will give you a better understanding but given you seem to want something slightly different than your original question I would suggest you do some editing or ask a new question to more appropriately cover your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use distinct  as you are looking for distinct combination

ie

```
select distinct MainID, ItemID, DeviceID,  ChannelID  from Yourtable
```

Comment: This works. But what if I need other columns too? If I include those extra columns, the number of rows returned is more. How can I avoid that?

Comment: what exactly you are looking just detail

Comment: The query works just fine but if I want more columns for example DeviceID,ChannelID,ColumnX,ColumnY etc. the distinct query doesnt seem to work. In this example the ColumnX and ColumnY could be additional coumns in the table

Comment: do you mean  like select distinct MainID, ItemID, DeviceID,  ChannelID ,ColumnX , ColumnY  from Yourtable it will work .. if you do not  please let me understand what is the ask

Comment: Sandeep will revert to you tomorrow in detail

Answer (score 0):

> **ROW_NUMBER()**

there may have many other solutions.
But to speed-up, your query's best use is to Use `ROW_NUMBER()`.
***Sample code***:

```
select
   MainID,
   ItemID,
   DeviceID,
   ChannelID,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MainID,ItemID,DeviceID,ChannelID) as COUNT_VAR
from Your_table;
```

It is faster than `GROUP BY` query because `GROUP BY` uses run_time generation of sequence number where `ROW_NUMBER()` uses SQL Server defined default indexes. 
Hope this will help you